# How does capacitive loading and inductive loading differ from resistive load?

Tags: resistance, capacitance, inductance, load

A voltage source is loaded when current is drawn from it. Usually we have voltage sources in circuits and not current sources. A resistive load draws current from a voltage source that is a function of its resistance as per the formula V=I*R.

Now while it is completely clear what it means to load a circuit i.e draw current, and it is also clear what resistive loading means, it is not clear what capacitive and inductive load means. I mean if everything is merely loading i.e draw current, then why make the distinction?

Is my definition of "loading", correct?

Comment: The distinction becomes very clear when you try to stop supplying current or voltage to an inductive or capacitive load. Imagine an amplifier with a square wave input but an inductor as load: when you tell the ampli to cut the current to the load, the inductive load says no, no, no. And as your ampli becomes more and more like a high impedance from the point of view of the load, guess what happens to the output voltage if the current stays more or less the same?

Answer (score 2):

Resistive loading will draw current in phase with the voltage. Capacitive loading draws current in advance of the voltage. Inductive loading draws voltage in advance of the current.

In a dc circuit at steady state a resistor will continue to drop voltage and draw current. An inductor will drop zero voltage and continue to draw current. A capacitor will drop voltage but will draw no current.